# Would using a parasite be Assault with a Deadly Weapon?

Tags: united-kingdom, criminal-law, england-and-wales, common-law, statutes

What crime would be committed if an Offender inserted a parasite into a victim's ear? This would be involuntary and for malicious purposes. The outcome could range from short-term discomfort to severe life-long pain. Assume no medical treatments are possible.

I was thinking of Assault with a Dangerous Weapon, however a parasite is biological rather than a knife, acid, gun etc...

**Jurisdiction:** United Kingdom (England & Wales).

Comment: What kind of parasite? Ceti Eels or Illithid Tadpoles?

Comment: Illithid tadpoles go in the eye. Do they not teach mind flayer sex ed any more?

Comment: Anything, I did not want to specify.